# sympy will not evaluate an expression to a numeric value

Tags: python, sympy

I'm using the python package sympy as a part of a larger program.  I have a complex equation with multiple variables that mostly works to provide me a numeric answer.  Every now and then the stars align and my output includes half the answer along with a portion sympy didn't evaluate.  Why doesn't sympy evaluate the sum below to 1?  Is there a way to force it to sum to 1 while keeping the form that sums from n=0 ... infinity?  I'd like to continue to use that form since it allows me to vary precision and to use sympy's internals to figure out when the sum should stop or throw an error.

```
# Why doesn't the sum evaluate to 1?
3.133251548562*Sum(0**n*binomial(0.5, n)**2, (n, 0, oo))

# Isolate the problem bit
x = Sum(0**n*binomial(0.5, n)**2, (n, 0, oo))
x.evalf()
  ∞            
 ____          
 ╲             
  ╲           2
   ╲   n ⎛0.5⎞ 
   ╱  0 ⋅⎜   ⎟ 
  ╱      ⎝ n ⎠ 
 ╱             
 ‾‾‾‾          
n = 0  

# The below works for n=0...100, but I give up useful functionality
x = Sum(0**n*binomial(0.5, n)**2, (n, 0, 100))
x.evalf()
1.00000000000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum doesn't evaluate to 1 because you used an inexact 0.5 instead of `Rational(1, 2)`:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> from sympy.abc import n
>>> assert S.Half == Rational(1, 2)
>>> Sum(0**n*binomial(S.Half, n)**2, (n, 0, oo)).doit()
1
```

Comment: Although 0.5 can be represented exactly in binary, SymPy treats all Floats the same: as inexact numbers. So functions that have known exact values don't (usually) work if inexact arguments are given.

Comment: Fantastic information!  Thank you @smichr for the clarity.